# mysql insert - select syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax

This is my query -

```
$q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT * from category c  WHERE category_id IN (SELECT category_id FROM category_to_store WHERE store_id = '".(int)$from_store_id."');
                ALTER TABLE tmp drop category_id; 
                INSERT INTO category SELECT 0,tmp.* FROM tmp;
                SET @last_id_in_category := LAST_INSERT_ID();
                select @last_id_in_category;
                DROP TABLE tmp;"

mysql_query($q);
```

I am getting this error on execution

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ALTER TABLE tmp drop category_id; INSERT INTO category SELECT 0'
>   at line 2 Error No: 1064

But when I run the query in database directly then I am not getting any error.
Please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [php docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) on `mysql_query'

---

mysql_query() sends a **unique query (multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database ...

---

So basically split your queries to multiple calls of `mysql_query' each with a single query and you should be fine.